# android image cropper does not work normally

Tags: java, android

I use 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+' to crop image in my app. But suddenly it started to work anormally.

It should be like this
https://hizliresim.com/uXnjuP

But now it is like that
https://hizliresim.com/iADrZp

I use Log.e to control where the problem is and app works correctly until this

```java
CropImage.activity(data.getData()).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
```

Could you help me please. Where is the fault?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    CropImage.activity(uri)
                            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                            .start(getActivity(), this);
                }

                if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bm);
                    CropImage.activity(tempUri)
                            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                            .start(getActivity(), this);
                }

                if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                        Glide.with(this)
                                .load(resultUri)
                                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                                .into(profileimage);




                    } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                        Exception error = result.getError();
                    }
                }

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
```

Comment: I changed android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/> to android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/> and it works but thank you!